# How do I write a function that will get executed only when the user interacts with the dropdown in the UI but not on model updates from backend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I use ng-change in select, it would get triggered both during model updates from backend and during a user interacting with the dropdown in the UI and changing the value. But, what I want is a way to differentiate between both and execute a function only when the user is changing the dropdown and not when the model is being updated by some other source. Please let me know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: A click listener on the options?

Comment: Please provide some source code indicating what you've tried.

Comment: It's not impossible, you could use ng-click directives for user interations when an user clicks on a certain dropdown element and ng-model/ng-change directives to get notified for model changings.

Answer (score 0):

> If I use ng-change in select, it would get triggered both during model
>   updates from backend and during a user interacting with the dropdown
>   in the UI and changing the value

This is not true. `ng-change` is tied directly to the browser `change` event. Updates to the model will not cause the expression in the `ng-change` to be evaluated. Here's a fiddle to demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/kvxaLajb/

The `optionChanged` only gets called when the dropdown is changed in the browser. When the `$timeout` function runs, it updates the model (and the select), but `optionsChanged` is not fired. It sounds like `ng-change` is all you need.